# How to use multiple engines (ejs and hbs) with Node.js and Express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, ejs, node-modules

I am trying to link (href) my `hbs` page to a `ejs` page in my `views` folder. I have installed consolidate as seen in other tutorials via going to the directory `npm install consolidate` and have added the code `var engines = require('consolidate');` and `app.engine('handlebars', engines.handlebars);` to my code but nothing works (I also know if you’re using “.ejs” extensions you don’t need to do anything). Can someone please help me out as I cannot view my pages due to this. I receive this error - "Failed to lookup view `employee/addOrEdit` in `views` directory...". I have added my folder/file structure below and code snippets. Thank you!
[folder/file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNwul.png)

server.js file

```
require('./models/db');

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

var engines = require('consolidate');

const employeeController = require('./controllers/employeeController');

var app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', engines.handlebars);

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views/'));
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({ extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'mainLayout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/' }));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
//render css files
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Express server started at port : 3000');
});

app.use('/employee', employeeController);
```

employeeController.js file

```
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Employee = mongoose.model('Employee');
//placeholders for added task
var task = ["complete presentation", "practise with nodejs"];
//placeholders for removed task
var complete = ["finish jquery"];


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render("employee/addOrEdit", {
        viewTitle: "Insert Module"
    });
});

router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.render("employee/test");
});

//render the ejs and display added task, completed task
router.get("/index", function(req, res) {
    res.render("index", { task: task, complete: complete });
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    if (req.body._id == '')
        insertRecord(req, res);
        else
        updateRecord(req, res);
});


function insertRecord(req, res) {
    var employee = new Employee();
    employee.fullName = req.body.fullName;
    employee.module = req.body.module;
    employee.mobile = req.body.mobile;
    employee.city = req.body.city;
    employee.save((err, doc) => {
        if (!err)
            res.redirect('employee/list');
        else {
            if (err.name == 'ValidationError') {
                handleValidationError(err, req.body);
                res.render("employee/addOrEdit", {
                    viewTitle: "Insert Module",
                    employee: req.body
                });
            }
            else
                console.log('Error during record insertion : ' + err);
        }
    });
}

function updateRecord(req, res) {
    Employee.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body._id }, req.body, { new: true }, (err, doc) => {
        if (!err) { res.redirect('employee/list'); }
        else {
            if (err.name == 'ValidationError') {
                handleValidationError(err, req.body);
                res.render("employee/addOrEdit", {
                    viewTitle: 'Update Module',
                    employee: req.body
                });
            }
            else
                console.log('Error during record update : ' + err);
        }
    });
}


router.get('/list', (req, res) => {
    Employee.find((err, docs) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.render("employee/list", {
                list: docs
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('Error in retrieving module list :' + err);
        }
    });
});


function handleValidationError(err, body) {
    for (field in err.errors) {
        switch (err.errors[field].path) {
            case 'fullName':
                body['fullNameError'] = err.errors[field].message;
                break;
            case 'module':
                body['moduleError'] = err.errors[field].message;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Employee.findById(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.render("employee/addOrEdit", {
                viewTitle: "Update Module",
                employee: doc
            });
        }
    });
});

router.get('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
    Employee.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.redirect('/employee/list');
        }
        else { console.log('Error in module delete :' + err); }
    });
});

//post route for adding new task 
router.post("/addtask", function(req, res) {
    var newTask = req.body.newtask;
    //add the new task from the post route
    task.push(newTask);
    res.redirect("/");
});

router.post("/removetask", function(req, res) {
    var completeTask = req.body.check;
    //check for the "typeof" the different completed task, then add into the complete task
    if (typeof completeTask === "string") {
        complete.push(completeTask);
        //check if the completed task already exits in the task when checked, then remove it
        task.splice(task.indexOf(completeTask), 1);
    } else if (typeof completeTask === "object") {
        for (var i = 0; i < completeTask.length; i++) {
            complete.push(completeTask[i]);
            task.splice(task.indexOf(completeTask[i]), 1);
        }
    }
    res.redirect("/");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to add both `engines`, `ejs` and `express-handlebars` in your `package.json` file

   ```
    npm i ejs
    npm i express-handlebars
   ```
2. Import dependency in `Server.js` file

   ```
   const ejs = require('ejs');
   const exhbs = require('express-handlebars');
   ```
3. Set engine to your `server.js file`

   ```
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.engine('handlebars', exhbs());
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
   ```
4. For rendering template, you need to set the file extension

   ```
   res.render('heyy.handlebars');
   res.render('index.ejs');
   ```

   [image]

This is your Folder Structure
Inside `main.handlebars` and inside `body` add `{{{body}}}` inorder to mark where layout should insert page